# Why executing Canvas.getContext('2d').arc method with exact same parameters yields different result

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I execute the following code:

```
context.arc(100,50,50,2,3);
context.stroke();
context.arc(100,50,50,2,3);
context.stroke();
```

Why does the result is an arc and a closing line instead of one arc which is actually two identical arcs drawn the same way?

The parameters for the functions are its center coordinates, radius and angles. 
According to that identical execution should give identical result to my understanding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because there are actually three segments on the paths.

The first arc draws a sub-path like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDiyo.png]

Then the path cursor is moved back to start since it has the same location as the first arc, and in the process it will create a line since all paths are currently connected:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z926j.png]

To avoid it you can break up the sub-path by creating a new one by using `moveTo()` and move the cursor to the position the next arc will start, or simply clear the current path and start a new:

### Example

```js
var context = c.getContext("2d");
context.arc(100,50,50,2,3);
context.stroke();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100,50,50,2,3);
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbxvZ.png]

To use `moveTo()` you would have to calculate the angle using:

```
centerX + cos(angle) x radius
centerY + sin(angle) x radius
```

### Example

```js
var context = c.getContext("2d");
context.arc(100,50,50,2,3);
context.stroke();
context.moveTo(100 + Math.cos(2) * 50, 50 + Math.sin(2) * 50);
context.arc(100,50,50,2,3);
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: I thought it is related to path since lineTo started from end angle. Thanks for clearing it up. Great informative answer!

Comment: No mention of the last optional argument for arc? direction (which if true draws the arc counterclockwise, effectively swapping the start and end points), which would have eliminated the need for the `moveTo`. thus `ctx.arc(100,50,50,2,3); ctx.arc(100,50,50,2,3,true);`

Comment: Sure, the ccw flag can be used as well, in this case. The focus was more to address *why* it happens in this scenario, throwing in a couple of examples showing how to solve it as proof of how paths work.